# statistics and probability. Homework

Tags: probability, statistics

I've been given the following problem:
if I have 8 red and 10 blue marbles what is the probability that from 4 marbles that I took fom tha bag 2 are red?

I missed some lessons. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom{18}{4}$ **equally likely** ways to choose $4$ marbles from the $18$.

There are $\binom{8}{2}$ ways to choose $2$ reds, and for each such way there are $\binom{10}{2}$ ways to choose $2$ blues, for a total of $\binom{8}{2}\binom{10}{2}$.

So the probability we get $2$ red (and therefore $2$ blue) is
$$\frac{\binom{8}{2}\binom{10}{2}}{\binom{18}{4}}.$$
Now all that remains is to calculate.

**Remark:** It is possible that in your course $\binom{n}{k}$ is called ${}^nC_k$, or $C(n,k)$, or $C^n_k$, or some related name. Note that $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$.